# How to use javascript to simply vuetify code?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

Here, I am using vuetify to display multiple buttons but doing that I have notice that many of the code repeating again and again. As I have many buttons there are so many repetition of code .Now, I am planing to reduce my code so that it can short and clear but I am not able to do that something like the code below:

> ```
> export default {
>     data(){
>         return{
>             colors: ["red","pink","purple","deep-purple","indigo","blue","light-blue","cyan","teal","green","light-green","lime","yellow","amber","orange","deep-orange","brown","blue-grey","grey"]
>         }
>     },
> } </script>
> ```

My code is here:

```
<template>

  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="500"
    outlined
  >
<div class="text-center">
  <v-btn dark large color="red" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Red</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="pink" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Pink</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="purple" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Purple</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="indigo" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Indigo</span>
</v-btn><br/>



<v-btn dark large color="light-blue" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Light Blue</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="brown" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Brown</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="orange" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Orange</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="green" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Green</span>
</v-btn><br/>


<v-btn dark large color="teal" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Teal</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="yellow" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Yellow</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="cyan" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Cyan</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="amber" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Amber</span>
</v-btn><br/>


<v-btn dark large color="lime" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Lime</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="grey" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Grey</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="blue-grey" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Blue-Grey</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="black" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Black</span>
</v-btn><br/>

<v-btn dark large color="blue" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Blue</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="deep-orange" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Deep Orange</span>
</v-btn>
<v-btn dark large color="deep-purple" class="ma-2" style="width:100px;">
  <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">Deep Purple</span>
</v-btn>

</div>
   </v-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat items in an array you can use v-for directive of vue. Your code will look as below.

```
<v-card
  class="mx-auto"
  max-width="500"
  outlined
  >
  <div class="text-center">
   <v-btn 
      v-for="item in colors"
      :color="item"
      dark large class="ma-2" 
      style="width:100px;"
      >
      <span class="text-truncate" style="width:80px;">
        {{item.replace(/-/g, '')}}
      </span>
   </v-btn>
</div>
   </v-card>
```

More details on v-for can be read here. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: How can I use this to change the color of my navigation drawer and menubar by clicking on the particular color.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the color of the navigation drawer and menubar to be changed based on the color of the button clicked? I would suggest you use vuex store for this. As the button is clicked update the store, from the drawer and menu-bar component listen for the changes in the color, and update the same. if you are new to vue, it may find difficult in the beginning, but its easy :) https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

Comment: Sir, after your suggestion I try to use vuex store but I am not able to do that after trying for several hours..... so, can you please show me some example????

Comment: Here is a full setup. https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-leakey-tgzmu

Comment: Is there any way to do without vuex store??

Comment: Yes, you can. If you are having a small app with all app-bar, nav-bar all in one page then... example pen https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/LYpNvYK?editors=1010

Comment: Yeahh I do have my app and nav bar in same page but I want theme to be pop up form not in a page ......for example like setting icon in app bar.

Comment: I have made some changed to the setup, you may like it. :D https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/LYpNvYK

Comment: Sir, I have refer the link but I have notice that sir is not using the vuetify theme.